Reference for ${}_nC^0 + {}_nC^1 + {}_nC^2 + \cdots + {}_nC^n = 2^n$
How can I find, or what is a good reference for:
$${}_nC^0 + {}_nC^1 + {}_nC^2 + \cdots + {}_nC^n = 2^n$$
I could write
References
[1] Binomial sums, Binomial Sums -- from Wolfram MathWorld
but I need something that looks more professional.

Hint: $(1+x)^n = {}^nC_0+{}^nC_1 x + {}^nC_2x^2 \cdots {}^nC_n x^n$ Also i think u mean $2^n$

This question is similar to: Algebraic Proof that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}=2^n$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why do you need a reference that « looks more professional » ? This is a very well known result that appears in any undergraduate text. If you want to cite a book you can take Serge Lang - Basic Mathematics for example.

DLMF equation https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.2.E3 professional enough?

Yes. That sounds good. Thank you for help.

As we know from Binomial Theorm that,
$(1+x)^n={}^nC_0 \ x+{}^nC_1 \ x^2+{}^nC_2 \ x^3+\cdots+{}^nC_n \ x^n$
$\therefore (1+1)^n={}^nC_0 \ (1)+{}^nC_1 \ (1)^2+{}^nC_2 \ (1)^3+\cdots+{}^nC_n \ (1)^n$
$\Rightarrow 2^n={}^nC_0+{}^nC_1+{}^nC_2+\cdots+{}^nC_n$
